# Is it possible to delay when Docusign hits the returnUrl?

Tags: docusignapi

We're using the Docusign API to set the return url so that the user returns to our application after signing the envelope, but we want more control over when that redirect actually happens. Is delaying the redirect possible? Not seeing that option in the docs so was wondering if I missed something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such option but you can easily do that on your application side. You can put a server side delay before you show the page to the user so that the browser would still show the previous page until the server gets back with a response from your page.
(not seeing why you would like to delay, most people like things to be fast, but if you wish - you can certainly do that on your page).

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue that we're running into is that it takes Docusign anywhere from a few seconds to 20 seconds in our experience to invoke our event configuration webhook (which performs some business logic). The redirect happens before the business logic happens so we're trying to find a way to deal with that. Yes it is certainly a 'unique' situation

Comment: thanks for explaining. FYI it is faster in production compared to the developer environment (demo) but there could still be some delays. What do you do with the webook exactly? do you get information from the envelope to show to the user?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to use webhooks (Connect) to confirm that someone has signed the document via the signing ceremony. As you've discovered, it takes too long for the notification to be sent by DocuSign.

Instead, I suggest either of the following:

- After the embedded signing ceremony has redirected back to your application, you put up a "busy wait" page while your app makes an API call to DocuSign to check that the document was, in fact, signed. In other words, do **not** wait for the notification message--doing so provides a poor user experience.
- Assume that the signer did sign, proceed with your interaction with the signer. In the background, if you don't receive the notification about the signature, deal with that issue at that time. Eg, don't make any final commitments to the signer until you've received the notification but don't block the UX waiting for it. Remember that 99% of the time, the signer did sign.